# Why is my images folder being created outside of my public folder in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, backend, laravel-9

[image: Images folder outside public folder]

I'm trying to make an upload photo feature for my website. However, I can`t access the photos currently as my images folder is being created outside of my public folder. Once I manually move the images into the public folder it works. How can I make it automatically create the images folder inside of the public folder instead of outside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `storage` disk. Just call like this way:

```
Storage::disk("photo")->getAdapter() . $photoName;
```

It will save the photo on the directory:
`storage/app/public/`

After that, don't forget to create the symlink. Just hit the command:
`php artisan storage:link`